# "Can not perform "Like" on System.Decimal and System.String."

Tags: c#

I have trouble with search through `DataGridView` for price (decimal), this code works for string types but gives an error when I try to search for price:  "Can not perform  "Like" on System.Decimal and System.String."
Here's the code:

```
BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
bs.DataSource = dataGridView1.DataSource;
bs.Filter = "price like '%" + Convert.ToDecimal(textBox16.Text) + "%'";
dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;
```

Comment: Why do you want to use `like` on a decimal? `like` is for pattern matching with placeholders. Do you actually want a simple equality check?

Comment: `like` is only for strings.  A numeric value can't be "like" another numeric value.  You can, however, convert the numeric value to a string and _then_ use `like` on the converted value.

Comment: Given that you're concatenating the result of converting a String *into* another String, can you not just leave out the Decimal conversion?

Comment: I tried leaving out decimal conversation, but it still gives an error.

Comment: You're not addressing the points made in the first comments. If that is because they are not clear, I'll ask with a concrete example: do you really want a search for a price of `23` to return rows where the price is `1234`?

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to use `decimal` as `string`, that is why you are getting error. You have to use operator for numeric values like `<, >, =` etc

```
BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
bs.DataSource = dataGridView1.DataSource;
bs.Filter = "price > " + Convert.ToDecimal(textBox16.Text) ;
dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;
```

Comment: @user2263271, please make sure to mark it as the answer when the time expires.